# Splitting String in C++

Tags: c++, split, scanf, esp8266, arduino-ide

**What I Want:**

To parse a MAC address string and get an array of six `uint8_t` values, having an input like **`string str = "01:23:45:AB:CD:EF";`**.

**What I Tried (And Didn't Work):**

```
sscanf(str.c_str(), "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &mac[0], &mac[1], &mac[2], &mac[3], &mac[4], &mac[5]);
```

*Why it didn't work:* I'm programming for an ESP8266 Wi-Fi Module with the help of the Arduino IDE. Even though the official cores for the Arduino board supports `sscanf()`, the cores for the ESP8266 don't. ([The solution to the issue given on GitHub](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/404) doesn't work, as stated by *nicjohnston*.)

**Least Preferred:**

Anything that uses up too much RAM, CPU cycles or program storage.
Also some stuff using or directly/indirectly depending on `sscanf`, `setjmp`, `longjmp`, (and several others) may not work.

**Edit:**
The answer by @m.s. below is absolutely correct, but I realized that after I had devised my own code (given below).

```
for(uint8_t i=0; i<5; i++)
  mac[i]=strtol(Serial.readStringUntil(':').c_str(),NULL,16);
mac[6]=strtol(Serial.readStringUntil('\n').c_str(),NULL,16);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific use case you can simply iterate over the string and convert the hex substrings to numbers like this:

- each substring consists of exactly two hex characters; let a substring be denoted by `XY`
- `X` and `Y` are either within `[0-9]` or within `[A-F]` where `A` *means* `10`, `B` means `11`, etc. (in decimal)
- the transformation from an ASCII value to the numerical meaning of one of those characters depends on which character set a char is from:
- if a char `c` is from `[0-9]`, its decimal meaning is `c-'0'`, i.e. substracting the offset so that the following mapping applies `'0'=>0, '1' => 1, ...`
- if a char `c` is from `[A-F]`, the mapping can be expressed as `c-'A'+10`
- the numeric, decimal value `v` of each substring `XY` is then calculated as follows: `v=X*16 + Y`
- the substrings are separated by a single char (here a `:`, but this does not matter)

The following code implements those ideas:

---

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

std::uint8_t getNum(char hexChar)
{
    if(hexChar >= '0' && hexChar <= '9')
    {
        return hexChar - '0';
    }
    return (hexChar-'A'+10);
}

int main()
{
    std::uint8_t mac[6];
    std::string str = "01:23:45:AB:CD:EF";

    std::uint8_t j = 0;
    for(std::uint8_t i = 0; i<6; ++i)
    {
        mac[i] = getNum(str[j])*16 + getNum(str[j+1]);
        j+=3; // get to the next substring
    }
}
```

Comment: @sbrm1 `mac` will contain `{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF }`, which **are** the hex values and **not** ASCII values

Comment: Your code is correct, thanks. But what is the logic behind it? (my input was wrong).

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to extract the content and store in the array. Then parse the array to get the respective `uint8_t` equivalents.

The regex could be like: `[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]`

You can refer to this reference link for more details about regex and how to use it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/

In C++, `regex_search` allows to search for the regex pattern and possibly extract the searched (or matched) pattern as well.

Comment: I'll check it out and let you know. Thanks! Oh, I think `[0-9a-fA-f][0-9a-fA-f]`  will also include lowercase. And apparently the regex will support all types of delimiters. Am I right about that?

Comment: Found out that Arduino doesn't support regex'es. Looking for a regex library. Found one: http://mctrl.ml/HRIRqG

Comment: It was a great answer, but can't accept it as I just found out that the only regex library for Arduino uses `setjmp`/`longjmp` both of which are not available for the ESP8266 core.

Answer (score 0):

I am too late, and m.s.'s answer is correct.

My answer is a bit different as it is using the  to compute the hexadecimal from a string of characters and the  to make it more c++11.
While I am not certain if it's supported on your ESP8266 module I hope it helps.

```
#include <string>
#include <array>

std::array< uint8_t, 6> MAC_fromStringToArray(const std::string& str)
{
    std::array< uint8_t, 6> ret ;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = std::stoi(str.substr((i * 3), 2), nullptr, 16);
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "01:23:45:AB:CD:EF";

    std::array< uint8_t, 6> mac = MAC_fromStringToArray(str);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: since the  does not seems to be available I changed it the traditional array.

```
uint8_t * MAC_fromStringToArray(const std::string& str, uint8_t arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = std::stoi(str.substr((i * 3), 2), nullptr, 16);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

It needs to be called differently:

```
uint8_t arr[6]; 

MAC_fromStringToArray(str, arr);
```

Hope it helps, I am afraid that without access to the same compiler as you it is diffcult to resolve your situation.

Comment: Got `'array' does not name a type` on `std::array< uint8_t, 6> MAC_fromStringToArray(const std::string& str)` (line 4).

Comment: That's odd, maybe the #include<array> is not processed appropriately? Do you need to add a flag for c++11 like -std=c++11 for g++ ?

Comment: Actually I'm programming for the embedded ESP8266 platform, and the compiler is integrated in the IDE. At present, several things are not supported, however, they are scheduled to be fixed in later revisions.

Comment: I edited the answer to add a method which does not need the #include <array>